# PHP Pagination using count and possibly group by

Tags: php, mysql, count, pagination, group-by

I am using COUNT and GROUP BY to only show unique results in a database query. EX:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT *,COUNT(clientname) 
   FROM recruitingForm 
  GROUP BY clientname LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage");
```

There is also the beginnings of pagination going on, but it is giving me the results of the entire database and not my smaller list.
How do i set up my db query in order to do that?

Comment: Could you just run `echo "SELECT *,COUNT(clientname) FROM recruitingForm GROUP BY clientname LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";` just to show us what the query looks like as we cannot see what `$offset` or `$rowsperpage` is.

Comment: $offset = 0 and $rowsperpage = 20

Answer (score 1):

Fixed - By removing COUNT(clientname). LIMIT was never in my pagination code to begin with.